# What is the difference between Site Link Bridges and BASL?

Tags: active-directory, replication

I have a hub and spoke network where the spokes can't communicate with each other.  I understand that BASL is what's responsible for making links to sites that are non routable.

How does a Site Link Bridge interact with BASL on or off?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of what BASL does may be incorrect here. BASL should be turned off for networks that are *not* fully routed. With BASL enabled (i.e. the default), the KCC assumes that all sites are able to communicate directly.

If you have a network which is not fully routed, then you should turn BASL off and define your replication links according to your network's routes.

Comment: so no bridges are needed?

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll need to define site link bridges manually, but if your network is not fully routed then you will need to manually define replication links in order to prevent replication errors.

Comment: OK replication links created, BASL will be turned off. I had no idea I could hit properties on the IP object here for BASL.  I always thought BASL and ISTG were the same.  Not clear on the difference, but believe you https://vdh3ig.dm1.livefilestore.com/y1pUSjrjHXqL_qy4VdZ_Kc41-a6mJIAufwAzO7DekwFke7tTWWZfFXrnbq58PFAtTW4bVlmU9X8O_Sv2EEPvVRTIRXGNlS5qNJJ/AD%20Site%20Design%20-%20Disable%20BASL.jpg?psid=1